# How do I solve an algebraic equation of the form $\alpha |x| + \beta x = \gamma $ with respect to x?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given an equation of form:
$$ \alpha |x| + \beta x = \gamma $$
Where $x, \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$,

how do you find solutions for $x$?

Comment: Consider separately $x\geq 0$ and $x\lt 0$, making sure the signs and relative sizes of $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are compatible with those assumptions.

Comment: This is strictly taken not an algebraic equation... And well, try to solve it for special values of $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ like $1,1,0$...